# XSLT add new instance of a repeated node

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and am looking for a way to add a repeating node/element to an existing list. Here is an example xml.  How would I add new instance of a dog or cat using XSLT?

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Animals>
    <Cats>
        <Cat>
            <Name>Felix</Name>
            <Color>Orange</Color>
            <Gender>Male</Gender>
            <Age>5</Age>
        </Cat>
        <Cat>
            <Name>Fluffy</Name>
            <Color>White</Color>
            <Gender>Female</Gender>
            <Age>4</Age>
        </Cat>      
        <Cat>
            <Name>Shadow</Name>
            <Color>Black</Color>
            <Gender>Female</Gender>
            <Age>2</Age>
        </Cat>          
    </Cats>
    <Dogs>
        <Dog>
            <Name>Spot</Name>
            <Color>White/Brown/Black</Color>
            <Gender>Male</Gender>
            <Age>11</Age>
        </Dog>
        <Dog>
            <Name>Rocky</Name>
            <Color>Black</Color>
            <Gender>Male</Gender>
            <Age>8</Age>
        </Dog>      
        <Dog>
            <Name>Goldie</Name>
            <Color>Gold</Color>
            <Gender>Female</Gender>
            <Age>3</Age>
        </Dog>          
    </Dogs> 
</Animals>`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What have you read that doesn't make sense to you or tried that is not working?

Comment: Where would the properties of the new  dog or cat come from?

Comment: I would be manually updating the XSLT and using it to update the XML with new Data.  Currently my company has a similar XML that we update to add shortcuts to a custom shell.  Some of the locations need additional shortcuts that others don't so currently we have several versions of the same XML.  Which is difficult to manage because next global update would erase the "customized" version of said XML.  We were hoping to use XSLT to manage this, but we are a small company and none of us are experienced with XSLT at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would be manually updating the XSLT and using it to update the XML
>   with new Data.

I don't think that's a good method, but if you want, it can be done quite easily as:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cats">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <Cat>
            <Name>New Cat</Name>
            <Color>New Cat's Color</Color>
            <Gender>New Cat's Gender</Gender>
            <Age>New Cat's Age</Age>
        </Cat>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Dogs">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <Dog>
            <Name>New Dog</Name>
            <Color>New Dog's Color</Color>
            <Gender>New Dog's Gender</Gender>
            <Age>New Dog's Age</Age>
        </Dog>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

A smarter way would use an external XML document with the additional data, for example:

**Additions.xml**

```
<Animals>
    <Cats>
        <Cat>
            <Name>New Cat</Name>
            <Color>New Cat's Color</Color>
            <Gender>New Cat's Gender</Gender>
            <Age>New Cat's Age</Age>
        </Cat>    
    </Cats>
    <Dogs>
        <Dog>
            <Name>New Dog</Name>
            <Color>New Dog's Color</Color>
            <Gender>New Dog's Gender</Gender>
            <Age>New Dog's Age</Age>
        </Dog>
    </Dogs> 
</Animals>
```

and have the stylesheet combine it with the data in the processed XML input:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- path to the additions document -->
<xsl:param name="additions" select="'additions.xml'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cats">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document($additions)/Animals/Cats/Cat"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Dogs">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document($additions)/Animals/Dogs/Dog"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly.  You are the man! or Woman, you could be a woman. LOL

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to update the xslt manually every time... you can use some thing like this, you need to keep adding the Dog/Cat nodes as required

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/Animals/Cats/Cat">
<Cat>
        <Name>New</Name>
        <Color>New</Color>
        <Gender>New</Gender>
        <Age>500</Age>
    </Cat>
    <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="/Animals/Dogs/Dog">
<Dog>
        <Name>New</Name>
        <Color>New</Color>
        <Gender>New</Gender>
        <Age>500</Age>
    </Dog>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This adds a new instance of `Cat` to every existing `Cat`!